# Java converting keycode to string or char

Tags: java, string, keyevent, keycode

I want to turn keyevent keycode value into a string or a char value. Either one would do.

For example, when  I press 'SPACE', which 'lets say' has a keycode 20, and I want to convert that value to a char or a string. Is there any standard way of doing so, or I have to write a bunch of 'if' statements for every key on the keyboard?

Comment: Do you mean something like [KeyEvent.getKeyText()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyText%28int%29)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Cast it to Char.

```
Char c=(Char)keycode;
```

Comment: that was simple O_O Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

If e is the variable parameter of the KeyEvent, use

```
 e.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode())
```

But preferably use it in a static context of KeyEvent

```
KeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode())
```

It returns a string but you can cast to or get value of string returned in other parsable data types

Answer (score 2):

Just cast it to a character, but not with capital c:

```java
char c = (char) 20;
```

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to **load all the values in a Map** and just get the value for each key pressed. Like if you press a SPACE-KEY and get input as 20, just get the value associated with that key from the map and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Another option similar to Reujoe is to use `getKeyChar()` if you have they KeyEvent variable.

`e.getKeyChar()`

It returns the character representation of the keycode as a `Char`